# Remove unused Amazon EC2 Snapshots

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Since Amazon switched from ec2-ami-tools to awscli (check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545182/how-do-i-install-ec2-api-tools-in-14-10-utopic)) Robert Sindall's [solution](http://www.robertsindall.co.uk/blog/how-to-clean-up-amazon-ebs-volumes-and-snapshots/) is no longer acceptable.

So I decided to rewrote his script for new python/json standards.

Feel free to ask any questions or provide your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, install and configure [awscli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html) properly. For MacOS I would recommend [brew](http://brewformulas.org/Awscli) version.

After installation don't forget to run `aws configure`

Works flawlessly for me but anyway USE IT AT YOUR OWN RISK.

```
import json, subprocess

def remove_unused_snaps(region):
    line = 'aws ec2 describe-images --region {} --owners self'.format(region)
    p = subprocess.Popen(line.split(),
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    obj = json.loads(out.decode("utf-8"))

    snaps_used = set(i['BlockDeviceMappings'][0]['Ebs']['SnapshotId'] for i in obj['Images'])

    line = 'aws ec2 describe-snapshots --region {} --owner-ids self'.format(region)
    p = subprocess.Popen(line.split(),
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    obj = json.loads(out.decode("utf-8"))

    snaps_old = set(i['SnapshotId'] for i in obj['Snapshots'])

    line = 'aws ec2 delete-snapshot --region {} --snapshot-id'.format(region)
    for snap in list(snaps_old - snaps_used):
        p = subprocess.Popen(line.split() + [snap],
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        out, err = p.communicate()
        print(snap, out, err)
```

Then simply run it: `remove_unused_snaps('us-west-2')`